# Python - matplotlib - How to plot a space even when .bar() takes a zero value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import pylab as p
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

fig = p.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plot = fig.add_subplot(111)            

ind = range(10)          

bar1 = plot.bar(ind,l,facecolor='#777777')

# x-axis
plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))
plot.set_xticklabels(headings)

p.show()
```

value of l on first run:

```
l=[29, 28, 35, 32, 31, 27, 36, 40, 59, 60]
```

value of l on second run:

```
l=[13,1,18,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

See photo for results:
http://s1362.photobucket.com/user/superempl/media/figure_1a_zpsf281ca7b.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Problem:  A bar is not created when the value being passed in from list l is 0, even though the bar doesn't exist I would still like a space to be created as if it were.

The issue I face is that when list l's first and last value != 0 then 10 bar charts are produced (which is what I want), but when either the first or last value/s = 0 then less than 10 bars get created and thus the width of the bars changes (as you can see in the photo).

How would one solve this problem please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this just before `p.show()`:

```
plot.set_xlim([0,len(l)])
```

Comment: this should be `matplotlib.pyplot.xlim` or `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim`?

Comment: @Sam `plot` is an instance of `matplotlib.axes.Axes`, as you can check with `isinstance(plot,matplotlib.axes.Axes)`. Anyways I think the issue in the question is fixed on current Matplotlib version (3.0.x).

Comment: My mistake, misread how the `plot` was defined in the question